# mysql rownum is causing error

Tags: mysql, rownum

I'm trying to write a query that will delete a users oldest rows (record of viewed car) if they have more than 10 rows in my table.

I was using rownum to collect the items from 1-10 (which will be excluded from delete)...however rownum has caused an error (shown below).

Can anyone help me resolve this error or come up with a different approach?

```
DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE `car_id` NOT IN   
( SELECT alias_table.`car_id` FROM
   ( SELECT `car_id` FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `id` DESC ) AS alias_table
  WHERE rownum < 10 AND user_id = 0
);
```

> **Error**: Unknown column 'rownum' in 'where clause'

Comment: And what is rownum actually?

Comment: And what is rownum actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your rownum is not in any select list. Is it from the table or is it a calculated row ? Fixing your query depends on answer for that question.

If you want to delete all the records for a user other than latest ten records, you can use something like below.

```
DELETE FROM my_car WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT temp.id FROM (SELECT id FROM my_car mc WHERE mc.user_id = 1 ORDER BY mc.id DESC LIMIT 10) AS temp) AND user_id = 1;
```

Comment: My MySQL is saying: "Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: Then problem get complex and have to write a query with `JOIN`s. :) And BTW who are you? same user asked the question?

Comment: No, not same user.  I was trying to solve the question with: "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE car_id NOT IN ( SELECT car_id FROM my_table ORDER BY car_id DESC LIMIT 10);" but MySQL didn't like it...

Comment: Run this query and see. `DELETE FROM my_car WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT temp.id FROM (SELECT id FROM my_car mc WHERE mc.user_id = 1 ORDER BY mc.id DESC LIMIT 10) AS temp) AND user_id = 1;`

Comment: I will take a look at this again tomorrow, but for now it looks like it deleted all of the users cars (not just 10). It's just a Dev site so no prob.

I had revised it since the table name is not my car, so here's basically what I ran...

DELETE FROM `my_table` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN 
(SELECT temp.id FROM 
(SELECT `id` FROM `my_table` mc WHERE mc.user_id = 1 ORDER    BY mc.id DESC LIMIT 10) 
AS temp) AND user_id = 17

Comment: The query will delete all rows but will not delete most latest 10 records. Your query has a problem. `mc.user_id = 1` in inner query and in outside `user_id = 17`.

Comment: opps, missed that one! This seems to work. Thank you very much :> I don't use SQL too often so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you are giving SQL the rownum column to find in the where clause like the error states, or in other words: your sub-query only returns "car_id" and excludes rownum.

If you include rownum, e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE ``car_id`` NOT IN   
( SELECT alias_table.``car_id`` FROM
  ( SELECT ``car_id``, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum FROM ``my_table``, (select @rownum:=0) tmp ORDER BY `id` DESC ) AS alias_table
  WHERE rownum < 10 AND user_id = 0
);
```

Then your query should work, assuming your the rest of your syntax is correct for your mysql version which it appears to be.

Hope that helps!

**Thanks to Reno for catching my mistake and actually declaring rownum! Good catch :)**

Comment: How interesting, you can't use LIMIT in a subquery!

Comment: This is true.  I think I may have jumped the gun in assuming "rownum" was being used in proper context.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try your solution, though I've now realized the rownum function is only for oracle...http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

I thought rownum had some kind of reference to the index of the rows.